# WHERE condition with a name containing a space in SQL Server

Tags: php

I have an issue with a SQL query in SQL Server. I'm trying to retrieve a list of movements made by a carrier in the past 7 days from my database.

```
$nom = $_GET['transp'];
$db = DbConnect::getDb();
$q = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM View_Mouvements_Transporteurs
WHERE nomTransporteur = :nomTransporteur
AND dateMouvement BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
ORDER BY dateMouvement DESC');
$q->bindValue(':nomTransporteur', $nom, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
$listMouvements = [];

while ($data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($data != false) {
        $listMouvements[] = $data;
    }
}
```

I get results for carriers with names that have no spaces, but if the 'nomTransporteur' contains one or more spaces, I don't get any data, and I get this warning:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://xxxxxxxxx:xxxx/index.php?page=ListeMouvementsTransporteurAPI&transp=LE CALVEZ): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in

I've tried putting '[]' around the name, using '`' like in MySQL.

I've also tried removing spaces and changing my condition to `LIKE` and adding `%` before and after. Nothing is making a difference.

Comment: The problem, here, appears to be the application code, not the SQL, however, you've not tagged what the language you are using is, so you aren't going to get any attention from users that can help you.

Comment: Any difference using `bindParam` instead of `bindValue`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning not much. don't use either, just send values into execute()

Comment: this question is better be deleted, due to misleading title (and being a duplicate)

Comment: Looks like the warning has nothing to do with the code you posted; PDO should not have any issues with a string that contains spaces. The code that requests the page... it needs url encoding.

Comment: I had forgotten to specify PHP. Thank you.
There is no difference between bindParam and bindValue in my case.
The error is accurate because if I remove the space from 'nomTransporteur' and replace it with '-' for example, the code works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to handling spaces in the `nomTransporteur` value, and it's also causing problems with the HTTP request when spaces are present.

When passing data through the `URL`, it's a good practice to `URL encode` the parameter to handle spaces and special characters properly. Update your HTTP request to encode the `nomTransporteur` parameter and try:

```
$nom = urlencode($_GET['transp']);
```